# How to create a mapped type for resolved promises in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to have a mapped type that has resolved promise values.

This mapped type promisifies all the keys:

```
type PromisifiedKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Promise<T[K]> }
```

I want a mapped type that un-promisifies/resolves them:

```
type PromisifiedKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: UnPromise<T[K]> }
```

I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: I was trying for 30 minutes but without success. Maybe this utility types will help to find a solution somehow.. https://github.com/tycho01/typical/blob/master/src/object.ts

Comment: Looks cool, thanks! Doesn't seem like it will solve this problem though... Thanks anyway!

Comment: yeah.. it's not going to solve, but there is plenty of useful types there. Regarding the question, I don't know how to do that, but we need to extract type `TResult1` from `.then<TResult1, TResult2 = never>` portion of a promise. if `A<B> = Promise<B>`, then we could do `A['then']` which equals to the type of the `.then()` function, but to infer types further I have no idea :-( Also it's not clear what to do if one of the promises actually fails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Typescript 2.8 there are conditional types. From the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

```
type Unpacked<T> =
    T extends (infer U)[] ? U :
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer U ? U :
    T extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
    T;
```

Usage example:

```
const p: Promise<string> = getData();
type ReturnDataType = Unpacked<p>;
```

I was able to implement this as such:

```
interface AsyncSupplementalData {
    couponCodeData: Promise<string>;
}
interface ApplicationState {
    [K in keyof AsyncSupplementalData]: Unpacked< AsyncSupplementalData[K] >
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You really want [mapped conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424), which don't currently exist in TypeScript.

---

There are workarounds.  If you're willing to [pollute the global declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) of `Promise<T>` with a phantom property, you can do this:

```
declare global {
  interface Promise<T> {
    "**unPromise**": T
  }
}
export type UnPromise<T extends Promise<any>> = T['**unPromise**']
export type UnPromisifiedKeys<T extends { [k: string]: Promise<any> }> = 
  {[K in keyof T]: UnPromise<T[K]> }
```

And you get:

```
type Promised = {
  foo: Promise<string>,
  bar: Promise<number>
}
type UnPromised = UnPromisifiedKeys<Promised>; 
// {foo: string, bar: number}
```

This is more or less what you asked for, but it's hacky.

---

Or, you could use [inference from mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#inference-from-mapped-types) to have a function that takes an object of type `PromisifiedKeys<T>` and returns a `T`:

```
declare function unPromisifyKeys<T>(k: PromisifiedKeys<T>): T;
```

This represents as a function what you want to do with the types.  If you have concrete things you want to pass to this function, it might be useful to you.  (That is, if you were just looking for `UnpromisifyKeys<T>` as a way to represent the output of a function, then this solution will work as-is).  If you really need to figure out `UnpromisifyKeys<T>` at the type level without a concrete `T` value, then you can jump through hoops to force the compiler to infer the right type without causing too much busy work at runtime:

```
const unpromised = true as false || unPromisifyKeys(null! as Promised);
type Unpromised = typeof unpromised; 
// {foo: string, bar: number}
```

This *works* but it is ugly.  The only thing it has going for it over the first workaround is that the global definition of `Promise<T>` is unchanged.

---

Maybe one of those workarounds is good enough for you? Hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since TypeScript 4.5, you can also use the [Awaited](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype) utility type.

`Awaited` is pretty much exactly the `Unpromise` template that you are looking for.

```
type UnpromisifiedKeys<T> = { [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]> }
```